Principal Filters and Neighborhood Filter
I'm having trouble solving a problem using filters.
The problem:
Given X a topology such that every ultrafilter that converges is principal.
Show that for any collection of open sets  $(U_a)_{a\in I}$ the intersection $\underset {a\in I}{\bigcap U_a}$ is open.
I have tried this approach:
Assume the intersection is not open, then it's not empty and there is $x\in \underset {a\in I}{\bigcap U_a}$ such that for all neighborhoods $U$ of x, $U\cap X\setminus \underset {a\in I}{\bigcap U_a}\neq\emptyset$.
Then take $F_x$ the neighborhood filter of x, and $F_x\subseteq F$ were $F$ is an ultrafilter that converges. By the assumption, $F$ is a principal filter where $F_{(y)}=F$. From here, I am stuck and don't see where to go.
I would like some help and direction. Am I on the right track? My problem now is that I don't see why $y=x$ because the space is not Hausdorff.

I suggest the following path to solve the problem. I can elaborate the proof of each step if necessary.
Observation 1. The following statements about a topological space $X$ are equivalent:

All convergent ultrafilters on $X$ are principal.

Any convergent filter on $X$ has nonempty intersection.


Observation 2. The following statements about a filter $F$ and a point $x \in X$ are equivalent.

There exists a bigger filter $G \supset F$ such that $G$ converges to $x$.

$x \in \bigcap_{A \in F} \overline{A}$


Corollary. Let $X$ satisfy the equivalent conditions from Observation 1 and let $F$ be a filter on $X$. If $\bigcap_{A \in F} \overline{A} \ne \emptyset$, then $\bigcap_{A \in F} A \ne \emptyset$.
For the following two observations we fix a collection $\{U_a\}_{a \in I}$ of open sets and let $W = \bigcap_{a} U_a$.
Observation 3. If $W$ is not open, then the set $$B = \{(U_{a_1} \cap \dots \cap U_{a_n}) \setminus W: n \in \mathbb N, a_1, \dots, a_n \in I \}$$
is a basis of a filter. The filter generated by $B$ has empty intersection.
Observation 4. If $x \in W$ is not an interior point, then $x \in \overline{(U_{a_1} \cap \dots \cap U_{a_n}) \setminus W}$ for any finite collection $a_1, \dots, a_n \in I$.
The final steps of the proof are trivial: if $W$ is not open, then the filter generated by $B$ has empty intersection, but nonempty intersection of closures. This contradicts the foregoing corollary, if $X$ satisfies the conditions of Observation 1.

Thanks for the asnwer, manged to proof it by those idea.
